# How to send a DNS answer to a through a socket

Tags: python

I need to send the answer (www.google.com. 58 IN A 172.217.6.68) through a socket to another testing code.

I tried sock.sendto(message.answer.to_wire(),addr) but I get a message from the server saying AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_wire'

```
def process_message(sock):
    global cache, pending_requests

    # Listen for an incoming UDP message through the socket
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(BUFFERSIZE)
    message = dns.message.from_wire(data)



    sock.sendto(message.to_wire(),(GOOGLE_DNS, DNS_PORT))
    sock.sendto(message.answer.to_wire(),addr)


# Open a UDP socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    # Listen on the PORT for traffic destined to any IP address
    s.setblocking(0)
    s.bind(('', PORT))

    # Read from the socket without blocking, to allow CTRL+C to exit our program
    inputs = [s]
    outputs = []
    while inputs:
        # Waiting for a UDP message
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)

        for sock in readable:
            # Socket has data, read from it
            process_message(sock)
```

tester code

```
# Listen for a response from the nameserver
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(BUFFERSIZE)
    message = dns.message.from_wire(data)
    if len(message.answer) == 0:
        print("No ANSWER records in response.")
    else:
        # Print the DNS answer records
        for answer in message.answer:
            print(answer.to_text())
```

I expect to get the answer from the dns to the tester code (www.google.com. 58 IN aA 172.217.6.68), but I get an error in the server code and no answer in the tester.

Answer (score 0):

So the line of your code is causing the error is:

```
sock.sendto(message.answer.to_wire(),addr)
```

According to the documentation of the **Message** class, its **answer** attribute returns a **list of dns.rrset.RRset objects**.

So **message.answer** is a list.  But you're trying to call a **to_wire()** method on it.  Since a list object in Python does not have a **to_wire()** method, you'r getting the error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_wire'**.

Is it possible that what you want to do is iterate over the **message.answer** list, and call **to_wire()** on each of the objects contained in that list?  According to the documentation, **RRSet** does have a **to_wire()** method, so I'm guessing that that's what you want to be doing.

...and maybe in your case there's always just one item in **message.answer**.  If you can make this assumption, then you could just change that line to:

```
sock.sendto(message.answer[0].to_wire(),addr)
```

or if you can have multiple answers, maybe you want this:

```
for answer in message.answer:
    sock.sendto(answer.to_wire(),addr)
```

Comment: That is correct, for every answer I want to transfer that answer through the socket to the tester.

Comment: So you're saying that it makes sense to iterate over the list and to send each answer through the socket to the tester?  If so, then just do it!

Comment: The issue that I saw was that `pending_requests` is unused and what the proxy should do when it receives a answer to a request is forward it. so `sock.sendto(message.answer.to_wire(),addr)` should be `sock.sendto(message.to_wire(),addr)` but the part that makes it function differently for requests from the tester and answers from the server is missing.